# ng hide image if the brackes is populated

Tags: angularjs

I have this bit of code, Basically when the image is uploaded the `logoFileUrl` will be populated, I'm wanting the placeholder to be removed if its populated.

Heres my bit of code

```
        <div class="thumbnail" ng-show="!$flow.files.length">
            <img ng-hide="{{logoFileURL}}" src="http://www.placehold.it/200x150/EFEFEF/AAAAAA&amp;text=no+image">
                <img ng-src="{{logoFileURL}}">
        </div>
```

Whats actually happening is the placeholder image stays and the second uploaded image is shown also

Heres the changes i made

i placed this in my controller

```
eventModule.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, flowFactoryProvider) {

    //$locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');
 logoFileUrl = '';
    $stateProvider
```

and i placed this in my html

```
  <div class="thumbnail" ng-show="!$flow.files.length">
                <img ng-if="{{!logoFileURL}}" src="http://www.placehold.it/200x150/EFEFEF/AAAAAA&amp;text=no+image">
                    <img ng-src="{{logoFileURL}}">
            </div>
            <div class="thumbnail ng-hide" ng-show="$flow.files.length">
                <img flow-img="$flow.files[0]">

            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

At the beginning of your controller, explicitly set `logoFileUrl` to empty:

```
 yourApp.controller('yourController', function...){
    logoFileUrl = '';
    ...
 }
```

Then, populate it after uploading.

In your html, use `ng-if`:

```
<img ng-if="{{!logoFileURL}}" .../>
```

Comment: but theres nothing inside that url so nothing should load.

Comment: That also din't work for me, just remove the placeholder

Comment: But what you wanted was to remove the placeholder, wasn't it?

Comment: remove the placeholder and show the image once the image has been uploaded

Comment: My code does exactly that. Can you post your code in controller?

Comment: i'll show you what i've got now it's a bit of a mess i cant copy the controller over because its huge, i put placed it at the top before any scopes

Comment: You put `logoFileUrl` in your `config`, put it inside a `controller`. see my update

Comment: so i put it here, `class EventsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :login_required
  logoFileUrl = ''` and it still hasnt worked it still removes the placeholder before an image has been uploaded